# IIS 6.0 Debugging methods

Tags: windows, debugging, iis, iis-6, windows-server-2003

I need some help from you about debugging high CPU usage (w3wp.exe) on server (Windows Server 2003 R2). I used debugdiag to anaylze but the problem is that this piece of software is not detecting any kind of problem.

Have you ever met any problem with high CPU usage on w3wp.exe (100% all the time)?

Have you got any tutorial how to debug any related problems?

Answer (score 3):

Use adplus in hang mode to gather memory dump

```
adplus -hang -pn w3wp.exe -quiet
```

More details here: [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 4: High CPU hang](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2008/02/22/net-debugging-demos-lab-4-high-cpu-hang.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to determine which program/process is using so much CPU. Have you used task manager to sort prtocesses by CPU usage?

Also I would recommend that you download the free tools from [Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/default.aspx) (now part of Microsoft).

Their [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) tool would be a great start.

Comment: Yes it is the w3wp.exe process that is taking 100% of the CPU